# Export files directly into the jar

Tags: eclipse, jar

How would I go about exporting the files directly into the jar, instead of it in a directory?

For example, here's my project tree:

```
project name
    src folder
        package
            Java class
    resources
        resource file
```

Let's say I want to export so that the JAR tree would look like this:

```
META-INF
src folder
    package
        Java Class
resource file
```

Notice the resource file is in the root of the JAR and not in a folder called resources.

Is there a way to do this in Eclipse?